# How can I get the .so file from .whl?

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I want to release the Django website.

and I only find the bellow link to download the `.whl` file:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

But how can I get the `mod_wsgi.so` file from the `.whl` file?

Because some tips says the `.whl` contains it, the `.whl` file can not unZip, alright?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off compiling it yourself. If you have Apache installed at `C:/Apache24`, it is a complete Apache with header files, and you are able to compile C extensions for Python when running `pip`, run:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

Then run:

```
mod_wsgi-express module-config
```

Copy the Apache directives that prints out into your Apache configuration file. That will load the mod_wsgi module and ensure it can find the Python library and installation as well.

Restart Apache to make sure it restarts, and then configure Apache/mod_wsgi to load your WSGI application.

For more details see:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: It is an Apache distribution, but I am not sure if it is a complete distribution. Where is it installed and does that directory contain an ``include`` directory with lots of ``.h`` files in it?

Comment: Yes, it has, the first file is `ap_compat.h`.

Comment: But what directory is Apache installed in? If it is ``C:/Apache24`` then you can simply run ``pip install mod_wsgi``. If not, you need to set the ``MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR`` environment variable in shell, and export it, where you are running ``pip``, with the environment variable have value which is the directory of the Apache installation. The path must use forward slashes, not backward slashes to be safe.

Comment: The apache path is: `D:\xampp\apache`

Comment: I have done the  `SET [MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=[D:/xampp/apache]]`, and what do you mean of export it in windows?

Comment: Why square brackets? I am more familiar with having just ``SET MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=D:/xampp/apache``. What is required as that environment variable be inherited by any process you run. If ``SET`` alone does that then you are okay. You only need have it set when running ``pip`` and not later.